# Does the size of compiled code into MSIL necessarily correlate to code speed?

Tags: vb.net, performance, cil

I have been playing around with different types of native code operations in Visual Basic and then inspecting the code with Reflector to see what kind of MSIL is produced. For example, I wondered, in a one line If-Then-Else different than an If-Then-Else split onto multiple lines, ie.

```
If x > y Then x Else y
```

vs.

```
If x > y Then
    x
Else
    y
End If
```

Turns out those two compile to the same MSIL. Then I wondered about the new If **operator**, similar to the old IIf **function**. It's important to note that indeed IIf is a function and so incurs the overhead of a function call, so while it seems concise, it has its drawbacks. Further, it evaluates both the TruePart and the FalsePart before returning a value, ie. not short-circuiting, so it can have unexpected behavior. So, I'll stick with the If **operator**.

Turns out, when you use the If operator for the same functionality, like so...

```
If(x > y, x, y)
```

The produced MSIL is much smaller and seemingly more efficient. Which leads me to the question in the subject.

Does the size of compiled code into MSIL necessarily correlate to code speed?

Answer (score 1):

At a very simplistic level, having more instructions to execute is going to take longer than fewer, but you cannot just say the size of compiled code correlates to the speed.

For a starter, your MSIL isn't running directly on the machine but instead will be JIT compiled to actual machine code at runtime with potentially further optimisations in the process.

Also the nature of the code makes a difference - a long piece of code that does simple arithmetic operations may run quicker than a shorter bit of code with lots of branches simply because the processor may mis-predict the branch, stalling the pipeline and slowing the program.

The only way to be truly sure whether one bit of code is faster than another is to run it and profile it on the appropriate target environment.

Answer (score 1):

As far as raw execution time (excluding overhead of loading and JIT-compiling the code), there is no correlation.

Loops are the prime example of compact code that may execute for a very long time. You can write a very short one liner that will never terminate:

```
void VerySmallAndNeverTerminates() { for (;;); }
```

You can also write code as complex and long as the compiler will allow that (once the JIT compiler is done with it) returns almost instantly. You only have to be smarter than the compiler:

```
void VeryBigAndFast(int n) {
    if (Math.Abs(n) < 0) {
        // Write lots of code here. What doesn't matter,
        // since it will never be executed. The compiler
        // probably isn't smart enough to know that.
    }
}
```

So, longer doesn't necessarily mean slower, although it will probably take longer for the Just-In-Time compiler to compile the code, and it may take longer to load the code if it wasn't in memory.

The only way to tell which of two alternatives is faster, is to measure. And most of the time, it really doesn't matter anyway.

Answer (score 1):

No.  A typical counter-example is loop unrolling, which gains speed at the cost of size.